# Building Emacs from source doesn't generate a native application on macOS Catalina

Tags: osx, gui-emacs, build

I've been trying to build Emacs 28 from source on my MacBook Pro running macOS 10.15.5. I managed to get the `feature/native-comp` branch working, but I found it to be too unstable, so I deleted Emacs and tried rebuilding off of the `master` branch.

Now when I build off of the master branch, I can't get the GUI'd Emacs to build. I've tried blowing away the source directory and rebuilding from scratch, but that didn't fix anything.

Here's how I build:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --without-ns && make
$ make install
```

I worry I might have bungled deleting the old app. Any suggestions on what I might try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the flag `--without-ns`, that means do **not** build Emacs specifically for the MacOS platform.  How about using `--with-ns` instead, or no flag at all?  The build script should automatically build Emacs for MacOS when building on that platform -- i.e., when **not** using `--with-ns` or `--without-ns`.  The package `Emacs.app` will be in the `nextstep` folder of the Emacs source code.

Here is an excerpt from the `./configure --help` output:

```
Optional Packages:

  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)

  --with-ns               use Nextstep (macOS Cocoa or GNUstep) windowing
                          system. On by default on macOS.
```

Comment: Sheesh… when did I make *that* typo? Thank you @lawlist! I'm getting a different error now, but I think I'm good on this issue.

Comment: For future readers: I also had to say `CC=/usr/bin/clang ./configure --with-ns` to get this to work on macOS Catalina. After that I was able to run `make` without any problems.